# Slideshow created using Jquery stops working after rotating for 4 times

Tags: javascript, jquery, powerbi

I'm using this jquery code to cycle through some power bi slides on a loop. Now we had a request to create a image slideshow as well. The logic behind the code is that the powerbi slides will run, then 3 images will be selected randomnly and this process will go on and on, on a continous loop. I've used the cycle function to rotate the powerbi slides as well as for the images and used the math.random to function to select multiple images.

This is the code:

```
// Continous Rotation

var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();
var i =0;

var pics = $('div[id^="images-"]').hide();
var j = 0;

(function cycle() {
// Loops the Powerbi Slides
divs.eq(i).show(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .hide(0, cycle);
        i++;

      if(i > divs.length){
            // Loops the Images
           var x = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * pics.length);
           pics.eq(x).show(0)
                    .delay(3000)
                    .hide(0, cycle);
                    j++;
                  }

      if (i > divs.length && j >= 3)
      {
        i = 0; j = 0;
      }
})();
```

**Issues Faced:** It displays the powerbi slides for like 4 times on a rotation and same with the images, however after looping for 4 times, the code stops and it displays a blank page. I checked via the dev tools on chrome and saw that all the elements were hidden and the jquery code wasn't functioning after the 4 rotations.

If however, I was to only use this part of the code(Shown Below) it would work fine and loop for several hours.

```
var divs = $('div[id^="content-"]').hide();
var i =0;

(function cycle() {
// Loops the Powerbi Slides
divs.eq(i).show(0)
        .delay(2000)
        .hide(0, cycle);
        i++;

})();
```

Pseudo Code:

1. Display PowerBi Slides for the length of it.
2. If all powerbi slides have been executed, goto images
3. Select 3 Images randomnly and display them
4. If 3 images have been selected, RESET & go back to displaying the powerbi slides and again execute steps 2-4

I'm hoping I've been clear with my query. I've tried to be as descriptive as possible.

Any suggestions on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `The loop breaks down` - can you be more specific in your description - is there an error in the developer console for example

Comment: @JaromandaX Rewritten it, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your cycle function into last if condition also like this:

```
if (i > divs.length && j >= 3)
{
    i = 0; j = 0;
    cycle();
}
```

Comment: Tried that, it does the same. The loop crashes, like it can't handle the load.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the cycle method from both the hide callbacks and adding it after the last if condition.